# Getting no proper error/warning in typescript/tslint when using unused variable

Tags: typescript, tslint

How can I make TS or TSlint to indicate that variableB is never used and read in my project. Im using  `"tslint": "~5.9.1",` and   `"typescript": "~2.5.3"`

My ts Angular file:

```
export class SongsComponent implements OnInit {
   variableA: number; //used in html template, should get no error
   variableB: number; //not used at all - should get an error 


  ngOnInit() {
  const variableC = 5;    //not used at all - indeed getting TS error

  }
```

When i prefix the variableA and variableB with private both yield an error.

I have made the settings below set to true in `tsconfig.json`

```
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noUnusedParameters": true,
```

Comment: TypeScript does not process, interpret, or consider your templates in any way at all. There are no errors because it assumes that, properties may be _accessed_. If it raised errors for unused properties, the feature would be useless.

Comment: ok so are there any task runners / other linters anything that could help me out in this ? i often run into problems in bigger projects and i would like to find a way not to look for unused properties/variales manually

Comment: I find the Code Lens in VS Code, which shows reference counts to be useful for this kind of thing, but it won't help if your properties are referenced in html files or the like. Also, this is a hard problem in general. Consider the code that may access such properties at runtime and not even be available for your tools to analyze. This is also the reason that optimizations like the google Closure compiler's advanced optimizations are dangerous.

Comment: You might look into the Angular Language Service IDE plugin if you are using Angular (looks like it).

Comment: thank you but i had it installed before already

Comment: so this doesnt help actually ;/

Comment: there are tools out there that can identify properties used in templates but it doesn't solve the general problem. JavaScript is reflective by nature.